# How To Request multiple QueryStrings out of one URL?

Tags: c#, url, request, query-string

My URL is built like this: localhost:56698/Default.aspx?`lehrlingID=114`
The `lehrlingID=114` that you see at the end of my url gets saved in a variable like this

```
lehrlingID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["lehrlingID"]);`
```

Now i have to check for another variable as well like this:

```
string md5key = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

My URL should look like this then: localhost:56698/Default.aspx`?`lehrlingID=114&?id=123904871029

how can i save the `lehrlingID` and the `id` in 2 different variables even if they are in the same url? And how can i get the QuestionMark `?` between my variables in the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create query string it should be in the form of

```
?lehrlingID=114&id=123904871029
```

The `?` should go on the end of resource like  you have:

```
localhost:56698/Default.aspx?
```

But after that, it should be `key=value&key=value`

After that:

```
Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Will work as expected.

Comment: It worked, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

concatenate the params using `&`

localhost:56698/Default.aspx?lehrlingID=114&id=123904871029

Comment: can you help me get my asking right back. i got banned from asking cuz i didnt know how to ask and how to programm back then when i asked this. you would really help me with a upvote <3

Comment: i gave you one too